# How do I copy text from vi?

Tags: mac, vi, zsh

I installed `zsh`, and I'm using `vi`.

I want to copy a line from `vi` to somewhere else.
How may I do this?

Comment: Could you clarify what is your environment:
• are you using `Terminal` or `xterm` (from `XQuartz`)?
• do you want to paste your line **within** `vi` or **within** another application? Which one?

Comment: I enviroment is Mac Mavericks.yes,i want to paster line within vi another appliction.

Comment: Are you using `Terminal` or `xterm` or something else I haven't been able to guess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Position the cursor where you want to begin copying.
2. Press v (or upper case V if you want to cut whole lines).
3. Move the cursor to the end of what you want to copy.
4. Press y.
5. Move to where you would like to paste.
6. Press P to paste before the cursor, or p to paste after.

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy,_cut_and_paste

Comment: thanks! you method only in vi .if i want to copy text from vi to System paste ?

Comment: Use the mouse :-)

Comment: the mouse is not effect

Comment: Are you running vi inside Terminal? Selecting the text with the mouse and pressing Cmd-C will put it into the system clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

I can't remember if the default `vi` is `vim` or not. If it is, and you don't have the mouse, you can get things into the pasteboard by selecting a range (using visual mode) and writing it to `pbcopy` (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867356/piping-buffer-to-external-command-in-vim))

```
:'<,'>w !pbcopy
```

Comment: Yes `vi` on MacOS X is `vim`.

Comment: i try it .it is cut,not copy

Comment: @fuyou001 this answer does not delete the selection. It is indeed copy, not cut. Maybe you forgot to type `w ` before `!pbcopy`?

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the text you want to copy in visual mode, then press `"+y`

`"+` is a special register, the system clipboard. Using `"+`-yank commands you can copy to the system clipboard, and using `"+`-put commands you can paste from the system clipboard.

- `"+yy` - yank the current line into the system clipboard
- `"+yiw` - yank the current word into the system clipboard
- `V"+y` - select the current line in line-visual mode and yank it into the system clipboard

Your VIM has to have clipboard support for this to work; `vi --version` should include a line `+clipboard`. I think the newest macOSes do have clipboard support by default, my `vi --version` on macOS Monterey is Vi IMproved 9.0 +clipboard.

If it doesn't, you can install your own version of vim or neovim with homebrew or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

1. Place the cursor on the line you want to begin copping or cutting.
2. The visual mode has three subtypes:

   - Press v to enter the visual mode.
   - Press V to enter visual line mode, where the text is selected by line.
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to enter visual block mode. In this mode, the text is selected by rectangle blocks.
   - Entering the visual mode also marks a starting selection point.
3. Move the cursor to the end of the text you want to copy or cut. You can use a movement command or up, down, right, and left arrow keys.
4. Press y to copy, or d to cut the selection.
5. Move the cursor to the location where you want to paste the contents.
6. Press P to paste the contents before the cursor, or p to paste it after the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, to be able to copy from vi to the system, I created the file

```
~/.vimrc
```

in my home directory.

I just added the line below to the file:

```
set mouse=r
```

Now, I am able to use the mouse to select text, do <kbd>⌘  Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

See vi's [`:help mouse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350712) for how this works.

Note: you may want to add also the 2 following lines, otherwise you may lose your default coloring when using your vi editor

```
colo default
syntax on
```